# Return 404 for the /web directory Symfony 3

Tags: web, directory, http-status-code-404, symfony

All my links are accessibles by mysite.com but also with mysite.com/web/

I would not like to redirect /web to / but, i would like to return a 404 for ^/web. I think it's possible cuz i saw a lot of symfony projects which return 404 error for the /web path

Thanks you all !

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your apache configuration so the document root points to /web folder.

Your apache config file needs to look something similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
ServerAdmin contact@mysite.com
RewriteEngine On

DocumentRoot your_site_path/web

<Directory your_site_path/web/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule .? - [L]
        RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks you first but i'm using .htaccess cuz i'm not on dedicated server.
I already have in the / directory a htaccess :

    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]

Now, my when you type example.com/ it's ok but when you tape example.com/web, it's okay too, so i have duplicate content. What i want to do is return a 404 when /web is on my urls.

Thanks you